# Jolt Spec skipping over first element in array

Tags: json, jolt

Input JSON :

```json
[
  {
    "e": "id1",
    "c": [
      {
        "title": "title1",
        "enable": false
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "e": "id2",
    "c": [
      {
        "title": "title2",
        "enable": true
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

want to create new property called filtered at same level as c that contains any item from c with enable property not set to false. So expected output is

```json
[
  {
    "e": "id1",
    "c": [
      {
        "title": "title1",
        "enable": false
      }
    ],
   "filtered": []
  },
  {
    "e": "id2",
    "c": [
      {
        "title": "title2",
        "enable": true
      }
    ],
  "filtered": [
      {
        "title": "title2",
        "enable": true
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I am using following spec

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "@": "&"
    }
    },
  {
    "operation": "modify-default-beta",
    "spec": {
      "root": {
        "*": {
          "c": {
            "*": {
              "enable": true
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
    },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "root": {
        "*": {
          "c": {
            "*": {
              "enable": {
                "true": {
                  "@2": "[&5].filtered[]"
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "@": ""
        }
      }
    }
  }
 ]
```

But it skips over the first element at top level completely and generate output like this

```json
[
  {
    "e": "id1",
    "c": [
      {
        "title": "title1",
        "enable": true
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "e": "id2",
    "c": [
      {
        "title": "title2",
        "enable": true
      }
    ],
    "filtered": [
      {
        "title": "title2",
        "enable": true
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Will appreciate any help in getting the spec right.

for every valid input it seems like spec is skipping over the first element at top level completely

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the below jolt spec to get the expected output JSON

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "c": {
          "*": {
            "enable": {
              "true": {
                "@3": "[&5].filtered"
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "@": "[]"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-default-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "filtered": []
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: This is also skipping the first element if the "enable" is set to true in first element in array.

Generated output in that case give empty filtered array.

Comment: I have edited the Jolt spec you can check now